# Permission denied when setting up environment variables for android sdk

Tags: android, sdk, ionic-framework

I have been following [these directions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZibG.png) to setup android development on a mac. I put the android sdk folder in my desktop folder so my path should be "Desktop/android-sdk-macosx", I followed the steps in the terminal but it keeps on telling me permission denied as seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMcQS.png).

I went to my home directory as well and did COMMAND+SHIFT+. to show hidden files in order to add to the .bash_profile file in my home folder but couldn't find the .bash_profile there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some details of my setup that works.

Note I put my sdk folder at home, e.g. `~`.

First, open up a terminal and type these commands:

```
cd ~
ls -a
```

Here is my session, and what is shows:

[image]

If you don't have a .bash_profile, then make one:

```
touch .bash_profile
```

Then, enter the command:

```
emacs .bash_profile
```

Then, set up your ANDROID_HOME and PATH, here is what mine looks like:

[image]

Note that I have the SDK manually downloaded, and I used homebrew for the NDK folder, that is why they are set up different.

Comment: Thank you much! That cleared things up for me and now everything works.